# Value Cannot be null, Parameter name: dataTable

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

I am using SQL Database and am calling a stored proc from VB.Net, however when I try and will my DataTable I am getting the error as per the title.

My code is:

```
Dim dt As DataTable
Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection(_connstr)
    Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand()
    Dim dateParam = sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@reportDate", SqlDbType.Date)
    Dim dateParam2 = sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@reportDateEndRange", SqlDbType.Date)
    'Dim reportType = sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@reportType", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    Dim companyId = sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@companyID", SqlDbType.Int)
    dateParam.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
    dateParam2.Value = DateTime.Today
    'reportType.Value = "'IRF', 'TRF'"
    companyId.Value = 1

    sqlcmd.Connection = sqlConn
    sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    sqlcmd.CommandText = "dbo.uspSearchRequest"

    Using sqlda As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd)
        sqlda.Fill(dt)
    End Using
End Using
```

But when i get to the line `sqlda.Fill(dt)` I get the error as per the tile.

I have tested these parameters in the stored proc and I get results.

Any ideas on how to stop this?

=========================== edit 1

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[uspSearchRequest]
@reportDate date,
@reportDateEndRange date,
@companyID int

as
begin

select 
null as [Report Manager],
null as [Report Detail],
null as [Form],
null as [Attachment],
req.OverallStatus as [Result],
req.ReportNumber as [Report Number],
req.ReportDate as [Report Date],
req.FormNumber  as [Form Number],
req.SubmittedTimestamp as [Submit Date],
req.ApplicantContactPerson  as [Applicant] ,
req.Brand  as [Brand],
req.Department  as [Department]
from ias.dbo.request req
where req.ReportDate  between @reportDate and @reportDateEndRange 
and req.RequestCompanyID = @companyID
end 
go
```

Comment: Well presumably `dt` is null (Nothing). We have no idea where you're creating the datatable...

Comment: My guess is that the stored procedure requires some other value that you are not specifying, so is defaulting to null which the database does not allow? Could you show the signature of the sproc as well?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in  sqlda.Fill(dt) and check if dt = Nothing

Comment: The DataTable is beign created immediately before the using statement, i will edit the question to reflect, and i have now updated with the stored proc. I have already put a break point and yes, dt=nothing

Comment: No, the DataTable is being *declared* just before the Using.  Declaring and creating an instance are 2 different things

Comment: thank you @Plutonix, ive not worked with vb for a while, and that comment has just give me that eurika moment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to initialize the DataTable first:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
```